# How to return content in a 403 response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

When my controller action does not succeed, I'm returning a 403 with some JSON data so I can include the details of the failure (e.g. ActiveRecord errors). The problem is, the response content (as seen in Chrome's developer tools) seems to be empty.

Should I be returning a 200 even though the requested action failed, and then check JSON data in the 'ajax:success' event handler? That seems a bit weird. Ideally, I'd like to access the data in the 'ajax:error' handler.

I'm new to API-style programming, so I'm not aware of the best practices.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is best practice or not, but I've done it this way:

In the controller, if an error occurred:

```
render :new, :status => :bad_request
```

new.js.erb is the original view including the form showing the errors.

JavaScript:

```
$('#the_form').live('ajax:failure', function(evt, xhr, status, error) {
  if (xhr.status == 400) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  } else {
    alert('Generic error message');
  }
});
```

Rails sends a 500 (:internal_server_error) when exceptions are raised. That's covered by the else in the JavaScript but as you saw, you don't get a chance to return an error or re-render the form in that case. I had to use a different status code so it would render the content but still hit the ajax:failure event.

Here is a [list of status code mappings](http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/7/4/rails-http-status-code-to-symbol-mapping). I chose 400 because it was the closest match.

Comment: It looks like you're using the pre jQuery 1.4.3 rails.js (the newer one has ajax:error). I wonder if that's my problem? The other difference was that I was returning a 403 status. I'll try your example and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: I'm on Rails 3.0.0 with jquery-rails 0.2.6. rails.js has ajax:failure. What version of Rails or jquery-rails are you using?